# Can't get site response headers in userscript(javascript)

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, userscripts

Deleted old post because there was to many mistakes. Sorry if this illegal and for my english. Trying to get additional file information like file-size from site. I use this Userscript to get headers:

```
var url="https://some.example.url/to/file"
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open('HEAD', url,false);
x.send(null);
if (x.status === 200) {

var headers=x.getAllResponseHeaders()
//Some how get informed about headers
console.log/promp/alert(headers)
}
```

Tried also this:[example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getAllResponseHeaders).
I can get all headers if I enter to direct link(when open video link in new tab). Theese scripts in other site like Google main page work fine. When paste link of logo to `var url=` it gets full header with content-length.
With "via" browser on android it work with main page of site that I need. Writed script in script tab, entered to site because XMLHttpRequest won't work without it and it worked.
In terminal with curl it work correct to:

```
curl -I $url
```

And it returns full head of site with length.

Also pressed f12 and finded HEAD element and there are all header that I need defined. But when use `getAllResponseHeaders()` it gets only 
3 values like:cache, content-type,update-date

Edit:

Tried with Gm_xmlhttpRequest. It work. Thanks to user "wOxxOm" :

```
...
//grant GM_xmlhttpRequest
...

GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: "HEAD",
    url: url ,
    onload: function(x) {
alert(x.responseHeaders)
}})
```

Comment: GM_xmlhttpRequest doesn't have getResponseHeader, see the documentation. It only has responseHeaders string which contains all headers. Also don't forget to allow it by adding `@grant GM_xmlhttpRequest`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked with `responseHeaders`. Can you write how can I get specific part of header like "date". And I don't understand why it won't work with XHR. I wanted make cross platform, GM not supported by browser that I tested ( Via ). I don't want create two scripts for same function. Also tried XHR with `window..onload=`. But it make same things.

Comment: responseHeaders is a string so you can use the standard JavaScript methods like regexp or split e.g. x.responseHeaders.match(/Content-Length:\s*(\d+)|$/i)[1]